# How can i defer the last line of code which follows after AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback

I've got the following code which gets the list of addresses from php script, then makes an ajax request to google maps, then creates markers and changes the zoom to fit the markers.

```js
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
$.getJSON('/dmvfinder/dmvsearch.php', {zipcode: zipcode, state: state, city: city}, function (addresses) {
 addresses.forEach(function(address){
  $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {address: address}, function(data){
    var p = data.results[0].geometry.location;
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: latlng,
     map: map
    });
    bounds.extend(latlng);
  });
 });
});
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

As far as i understand the problem with the code is that the fitBounds method fires before ajax finishes and the 'bounds' gets filled. How could i possibly defer the last line of code here?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Put that line of code in the callback function instead of outside of it.

Comment: @Pointy - that wouldn't wait for the inner getJSON's to finish, would it

Comment: Do you want your markers to appear and the bounds to adjust one-by-one or all at once?

Comment: @JaromandaX no that's true, it wouldn't.

Comment: As post is duplicate now, here is one simpler solution http://pastebin.com/xE7GxMMs

Comment: @Bergi, all at once...

Comment: @Parag Bhayani, that's an easy one, thanks)

Comment: @ParagBhayani Why not use a simple `$.when`?

Comment: @AntonPisotski youve gone for the easy, bad solution, rather than the easyish good solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change 2 things

1. Accumulate all the promises from the `address.forEach` - change it to a `map` and make sure to `return $.getJSON(..)`. This will give you an array of deferreds.
2. Wait for them all to complete using `$.when` - as this takes arguments, not an array, you can use `$.when.apply(..)` on your array from 1)

Like this:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
$.getJSON('/dmvfinder/dmvsearch.php', {zipcode: zipcode, state: state, city: city}, function (addresses) {
    // 1. Accumulate all the promises into an array
    var allPromises = addresses.map(function(address){
        return $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {address: address}, function(data){
            var p = data.results[0].geometry.location;
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map
            });
            bounds.extend(latlng);
        });
    });
    // 2. wait for them all to complete
    $.when.apply($,allPromises).then(function(){
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    })
});
```

Comment: Great, answer but I am not able to understand allDeferreds properly, would you explain a bit more about it?

Comment: @ParagBhayani look up what [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) does, and also what the return type of [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) is.

Comment: nice - I would dispense with the allDeferreds var myself ... `$.when.apply($, addresses.map(function(address) {` ... `}).then(...);` - but that's what I was in the middle of typing when your answer popped up :p

Comment: @JaromandaX thats going to be long and unweildly line of code. I would prefer to see what its doing - especially for explaining an answer. ie - it matches my 1. & 2.